# How to set up Active directory with TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, active-directory

I want to set up AD where I can use TFS addons like Start/Stop AppService, DataFactory BLOB copy etc.

I've used Default directoy tenant:
[image]

I added application into AD:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Then I created ARM Resource in TFS(with AD tenant id from above):
[image]

Then set up AppService stop task like this:
[image]

And when I run build I still get error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `Service Principal Id` is not valid. Follow these steps to configure an Azure service endpoint in VSTS/TFS.

Download & run [this PowerShell script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/master/Tasks/DeployAzureResourceGroup/SPNCreation.ps1) in an Azure Powershell window to generate required data for Service Principal based Azure service connection. Running this script would prompt you for:

- The name of your Azure Subscription name
- A password that you would like to set for the Service Principal that
  is going to be created
- Note: the script has been tested with Azure PowerShell version 1.0.2.

Once successful, the script would output the following details for the Azure Service Endpoint.

- Connection Name
- Subscription Id
- Subscription Name
- Service Principal Id
- Service Principal key
- Tenant Id

Attache a screenshot for your reference:

[image]

More details, check this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/

Comment: I created all keys and I made a progress. Altought I get an error about not default subscription is set up: Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId e002f637-334f-465c-8e51-7f6479c9b5xx -tenantId ********
System.ApplicationException: No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription. I already run Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Visual Studio Enterprise" in power shell. http://puu.sh/pXJXm/75ba70c2fc.png

Comment: I opened another question, can you please check